# finatra - getting the response data

Tags: scala, testing, finatra

I'm trying to extract the response data\context.
I have a server which listens to incoming get requests and I'm sending back a plain text.
the server is running and when I sending get request from my browser I see good results, but I want to create tests for my server.
the test is creating an HttpRequest and the promise gives me back the HttpResponse
when I'm trying to compare my expected result to the response all i get is:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: text/plain

Content-Length: 11

Thanks,
Dana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one way:
https://github.com/twitter/finatra/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/twitter/finatra/ExampleSpec.scala

another approach: 
val result = Await.result(f)
val response = result.getContent.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)